# Error in Tensorflow 2.5.0 while using Colab TPU - NotFoundError: Could not find metadata file. [Op.DatasetCardinality]

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu

**Note**: These same steps work without any errors on Colab GPU.

Please help me with this. I created a dataset and saved it as file

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(( features, labels))
tf.data.experimental.save(data, myfile)
```

When I try to load it

```
data = tf.data.experimental.load(myfile)
```

and run any function on the data like `len(data)`, `data.batch(16)` or `data.take(1)` then I get this error:

```
NotFoundError: Could not find metadata file. [Op:DatasetCardinality]
```

TPU config

```
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
# This is the TPU initialization code that has to be at the beginning.
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
```

Is it similar to this [TF1.14][TPU]Can not use custom TFrecord dataset on Colab using TPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58009029/tf1-14tpucan-not-use-custom-tfrecord-dataset-on-colab-using-tpu) ?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, and I believe I setup the access from Colab to the GCS correctly, so I'm starting to think that it may be related to the way I saved my dataset. I did it exactly like you `tf.data.experimental.save(data, myfile)`

Comment: I found this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53292) on the TensorFlow repo from months ago. In the issue thread, it's discussed something about lazy loading. I tried the proposed implementation but it still raised the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging I got this error:

```
UnimplementedError: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: './data/temp/2692738424590406024')
    Encountered when executing an operation using EagerExecutor. This error cancels all future operations and poisons their output tensors. [Op:DatasetCardinality]
```

I found this explanation:

*Cloud TPUs can only access data in GCS as only the GCS file system is registered.*

More info here: [File system scheme '[local]' not implemented in Google Colab TPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870656/file-system-scheme-local-not-implemented-in-google-colab-tpu)

Comment: I tried to save my dataset in a session *without* TPU onto GCS using experimental.save(...), and then read it back on a TPU session: train_set = tf.data.experimental.load('gs://ai-tests/NLP/data/train_set'), still got same error. I suspect the problem goes deeper than just file system scheme.